# I messed up bashrc codes and reboot the Linux mint to black screen

Tags: linux-mint

A few days ago, I accidentally replaced my desktop in Mint 18 with a virtual console with an errant keystroke. Not having an obvious way to reverse the changes, I logged in and typed exit to exit the console and go back to the desktop. Instead, the computer rebooted, and I lost God-only-knows-how-much unsaved work.

After showing the Mint logo and flashing a message underneath it far too quickly to read, the computer now boots only to a black screen. By pressing esc during reboot, I can get to a Startup Menu. I ran disk checks and memory checks using it, and they all came up clean. None of the other options in this menu help. I have no idea what to do.

The screen is clearly receiving power, and the black screen that it boots to shows a dash or underscore in the top right corner.

How do I get my computer back? It's an HP Pavilion laptop.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail on exactly what you've done before anyone can suggest how to undo it.  Can you remember what the "errant keystroke" was?  Your title mentions "bashrc codes", but you haven't shown any of those in your question.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to look at:

1. Can you enter commands into the screen?
2. Hit ctrl alt f1 (fn key too if you have it) to get a console. Also try ctrl alt f7 to see if you get a graphical.
3. Boot from install media to alter files.

Comment: Sometimes when a video driver goes wonky, the easiest way around is to ssh into the machine to fix it since the machine's video display is not working.  Of course, this only works if sshd is running.